Possible to intercept class instantiation in PHP?
Is there a way in PHP that, every time I instantiate a new class — e.g. $o = new SomeClass() — I can "intercept" that and actually return some other class?
Or, more specifically, I want to do something like $o = new WrappingClass(new SomeClass()) and wrap all the "actual" classes in something else.
I thought maybe something like hooking into composer's autoloader, but that's really just responsible for knowing which files contain which classes, and requireing them automagically.  I don't see a way to hook into class instantiation.
My suspicion is no, unless I'm using some kind of application container or factory pattern, and having all my classes instantiated that way.  In my case, that's not possible, as it's a legacy code base with several package dependencies, some of which's classes I'd like to be able to wrap.
Thanks!

I don't really see a proper way to do this without creating a new service i.e a factory.
This factory would handle how your object is instantiated. Proxies are a similar way to wrap classes but I don't see how you would "intercept" class instantiation since you would not be the one to manually create proxies.

You could write your own Autoloader. Or better use a Factory everywhere!

What are you trying to achieve by this?

@MarkusZeller How could you do this with a class autoloader? I presume you can abort code execution (never really tried) but I can't figure a way to make significant changes to code and then resume execution. Plus it would only get triggered once per program.

@ÁlvaroGonzález The autoloader is triggered when you instance a class which name was not known by require, yet. As stated before, I think it is a very bad idea and he should go with a Factory or overthink the software design in general

Legacy codebase + third-party packages... even if you could do what you are asking you'd be asking for a nightmare probably. This comes up ever once in a while here, and I've honestly wanted to do something like this in the past, too, as a form of "who is calling this in the first place". For me and many other people, the solution is a good IDE, sometimes along with writing a temporary abstraction/factory and manually dealing with the intercepts. In my mind, "legacy" means going away, not just "old", so hacking it is fair game.

I agree that the autoloader is probably a dead-end. It just requires the files, but has nothing to do with instantiation.
@ADyson asked why I’m trying to do this. A colleague is adding traceability to this old code base, the idea being that every time a class’ methods are called, some debugging info could get logged (e.g. a stack trace at that point of execution, values for all method parameters, etc.). His solution works, but relies on wrapping the class manually. I was mostly curious about whether it could be accomplished automatically, via some magic intercept I hoped existed.
